# how to serialize nested object without creating a serializer for the model in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I know that if I want to serialize nested comments of a model called post, I need to create a  serializer in app/serializer/post.js
something like :

```
import RESTSerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/rest';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
      comments: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
});
```

but what if I want to serialize this inside the app/serlizer/application.js ? 
I dont want to define a serializer for each model. Instead I want to be able to resolve the belong-to or has-many relationship inside the normalizeQueryResponse for example.

```
normalizeQueryResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    console.log(payload);
    return this._normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType, true);
  },
```

I want to be able to go thorough the payload and if a property in payload turned out to be object then resolve that.

does anyone know if that is possible?

Comment: why don't you create serializer for your model and inherit if from Application.js? so, you can do whatever you want in the application and if you want to customize each model then it will be possible as well.

Comment: @majid can you please explain what you mean exactly?

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/mhadaily/breweryUp-Ember/tree/master/app/serializers, I think it can give you a clue, If not, let me explain more, As you will see, for instance in beer.js, import ApplicationSerializer from './application'; and ...

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is possible and its how serializers and models are meant to work.  But I recommend relying on one model and not specifying the type in your case.  Lets take this example.

Your model post.js

```js
export default DS.Model.extend((
  valueA: DS.attr('string'), // converted to string
  valueB: DS.attr('boolean'), // converted to boolean
  comments: DS.attr() // not converted and set as it came in the payload
));
```

Your serializer post.js

```
export default RESTSerializer.extend({
  // assuming your payload comes in the format of 
  // { data: [ {id: 0, valueA: '', valueB: true, comments: [...]}, {id:1 ...} ]
  normalizeQueryResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    payload.data = payload.data.map((item, index) => ({ // item = {event_type: '', values: ['','']}
      id: index, // ONLY if your payload doesnt already have an id
      type: 'post', // set the model type
      attributes: { // attributes are the values declared in the model
        valyeA: item.valueA,
        valueB:  item.valueB,
        comments: item.comments.map( item => {
          // remap your comments to whatever format you need
        })
      }
    }));
    return payload;
});
```

Usage in your applicatioin

```js
this.get('store').query('post', {...query object...} ).then( 
response => {
  let firstItemLoadedComments = response.get('firstObject.values');
  // blast comments!
},
error => {
  Ember.Logger.error(`cannot load model: ${error}`);
})
.finally(() => {
  // set loading to false or something else
});
```